# pandas show multiple bar graphs on a chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

my data looks like this:

```
term    date    change1 change2
aaa  2010-03-01   23.00   24.31
bbb  2010-03-01   25.00   0.00
ccc  2012-05-01   100.00  100.00
```

The date column can have repeated dates. I want to plot for each term, what the change1 and change2 is. I was thinking to have the term as the x-axis and change1 and change2 share the same y axis but be plotted as bar charts side by side. 
I know how to do the y axis part but dont know how to set the x axis. I would also like each term to somehow show the date as well if possible otherwise this is not a priority.

Heres what i have:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
df.change1.plot(kind = 'bar', color = 'red', ax = ax , position = 1)
df.change2.plot(kind = 'bar', color = 'blue', ax = ax2, position = 2)
ax.set_ylabel= ('change1')
ax2.set_ylabel=('change2')
plt.show()
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

One way to make the labels along the `x-axis` to be `term`s is to set `term` as the index:

```
df = df.set_index(['term'])
```

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'change1': [23.0, 25.0, 100.0],
 'change2': [24.309999999999999, 0.0, 100.0],
 'date': ['2010-03-01', '2010-03-01', '2012-05-01'],
 'term': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']})
df = df.set_index(['term'])
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax.twinx()

df['change1'].plot(kind='bar', color='red', ax=ax, position=0, width=0.25)
df['change2'].plot(kind='bar', color='blue', ax=ax2, position=1, width=0.25)
ax.set_ylabel = ('change1')
ax2.set_ylabel = ('change2')
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Or, instead of setting the index, you could set the xticklabels explicitly:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'change1': [23.0, 25.0, 100.0],
 'change2': [24.309999999999999, 0.0, 100.0],
 'date': ['2010-03-01', '2010-03-01', '2012-05-01'],
 'term': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']})

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax.twinx()


df['change1'].plot(kind='bar', color='red', ax=ax, position=0, width=0.25)
df['change2'].plot(kind='bar', color='blue', ax=ax2, position=1, width=0.25)
ax.set_ylabel = 'change1'
ax2.set_ylabel = 'change2'
labels = ['{}\n{}'.format(date, term) for date, term in zip(df['date'], df['term'])]
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, minor=False)
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Per the question in the comments,
to create a new plot for each `date`, you could iterate over the groups in
`df.groupby(['date'])`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'change1': [23.0, 25.0, 100.0],
 'change2': [24.309999999999999, 0.0, 100.0],
 'date': ['2010-03-01', '2010-03-01', '2012-05-01'],
 'term': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']})

groups = df.groupby(['date'])
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=groups.ngroups)
for groupi, ax in zip(groups,axs):
    index, grp = groupi
    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    grp['change1'].plot(kind='bar', color='red', ax=ax, position=0, width=0.25)
    grp['change2'].plot(kind='bar', color='blue', ax=ax2, position=1, width=0.25)
    ax.set_ylabel = 'change1'
    ax2.set_ylabel = 'change2'
    ax.set_title(index)
    ax.set_xticklabels(grp['term'].tolist(), minor=False, rotation=0)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, just realized i have about 200 terms and its making the chart really messy. Is it possible to show per period, what are the terms and their change? So for each period, there is one chart for terms belonging to that period?

Comment: Is a `period` a `date`?

Comment: yes  it is a date but really the only difference between the dates if they are not duplicates, are the year and month.